# How can I make a CCAnimation with different delays between frames

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want a sprite that "blinks" so that it displays frame 1 for say 2 seconds and then displays frame 2 for 0.1 second and then displays frame 1 for 2 seconds again and repeats for ever. Now I can code this with CCDelayTime and build this logic my self, but it would be so nice if I could get CCAnimation to handle this or if there was a cleaner way.

Is there a way to create a CCAnimation with different delays between frames, or what is the best/easy way to archive my goal?

Thank you

Søren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCAnimation doesn't support this out of the box. Since we're talking about just two frames I'd find it easier to just animate it straight in code, something like this (pseudo code):

```
-(void) updateAnimation:(ccTime)delta
{
  [self unschedule:_cmd];

  if (first frame showing)
  { 
     [sprite setDisplayFrame:second frame];
     [self schedule:_cmd interval:2.0f];
  }
  else
  {
     [sprite setDisplayFrame:first frame];
     [self schedule:_cmd interval:0.1f];
  }
}
```

This has the added benefit of not creating and releasing actions all the time.

You could also try using a CCAnimate action and keep changing its delay property whenever a frame changed. But I'm not sure if that'll work correctly.

Lastly you could subclass CCAnimate to add an array of delays, one per frame, and customize the update method so that it'll take the delay from the delays array rather than using a fixed delay.

Comment: Hi Steffen. Thank you for your answer, I would like to go with the updatedAnimation method, but how do I use it? I have a subclass of CCSprite and was thinking about adding the method there, and should I then call [self schedule:@selector(updateAnimation:) interval:2.0f]; to start it?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what you do. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use CCSequence to create a sequence of animation; for each animation you can adjust the duration of if.
You simply create two (or more) animation with their duration and then do something like this:

```
CCSequence *sequence = [CCSequence actions:action1,action2,nil];
[sprite runAction:sequence];
```

Comment: I'd use this approach too and then add a CCRepeatForever action if it should be an endless animation loop